# How to get jQuery Hover to be stable when mouseout/leave

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery (3.5.1) In the below example I have difficulties with having the script being stable when mouse leaves the `TR`, the issue is that the hovering text and icon animation sometimes stays in the `TD` and are not reset to the `$originalText`.

Initiallly I made the jQuery global using classes in the hover instead of ID, and I had global class for the `.html`, and I have tried building it with `mouseout` and `mouseleave` but these efforts where more unstable than having a script per `TR` - yes, I know it ain´t pretty .. unfortunately, as you can see in the below code and snippet it does not work great, it initially does reset the hovering text to `$originalText`, but if you move over it multiple times or fast it will not reset the state back to original.

Can anyone see what the issue is, and how I can fix it?

**My code**

```js
var id = 315

$('#tr_user_tasksIT' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpanIT' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanIT' + id).html('<font class="text-success">CLICK AND GO TO TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-success"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanIT' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_tasksIT_NotDone' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpanIT' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanIT' + id).html('<font class="text-danger">CLICK AND SOLVE TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-danger"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanIT' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_tasksCFO' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpanCFO' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanCFO' + id).html('<font class="text-success">CLICK AND GO TO TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-success"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanCFO' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_tasksCFO_NotDone' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpanCFO' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanCFO' + id).html('<font class="text-danger">CLICK AND SOLVE TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-danger"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanCFO' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_tasksEconomy' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpanEconomy' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanEconomy' + id).html('<font class="text-success">CLICK AND GO TO TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-success"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanEconomy' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_tasksEconomy_NotDone' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpanEconomy' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanEconomy' + id).html('<font class="text-danger">CLICK AND SOLVE TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-danger"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanEconomy' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_tasksAcademy' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpanAcademy' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanAcademy' + id).html('<font class="text-success">CLICK AND GO TO TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-success"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanAcademy' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_tasksAcademy_NotDone' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpanAcademy' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanAcademy' + id).html('<font class="text-danger">CLICK AND SOLVE TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-danger"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanAcademy' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_tasksPublicator' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpanPublicator' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanPublicator' + id).html('<font class="text-success">CLICK AND GO TO TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-success"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanPublicator' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_tasksPublicator_NotDone' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpanPublicator' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanPublicator' + id).html('<font class="text-danger">CLICK AND SOLVE TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-danger"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanPublicator' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_tasksBogportal' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpanBogportal' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanBogportal' + id).html('<font class="text-success">CLICK AND GO TO TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-success"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanBogportal' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_tasksBogportal_NotDone' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpanBogportal' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanBogportal' + id).html('<font class="text-danger">CLICK AND SOLVE TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-danger"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanBogportal' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_tasksWelcomePackage' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpanWelcomePackage' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanWelcomePackage' + id).html('<font class="text-success">CLICK AND GO TO TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-success"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanWelcomePackage' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_tasksWelcomePackage_NotDone' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpanWelcomePackage' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanWelcomePackage' + id).html('<font class="text-danger">CLICK AND SOLVE TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-danger"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanWelcomePackage' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_tasksKeyCardDone' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpanKeyCardDone' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanKeyCardDone' + id).html('<font class="text-success">CLICK AND GO TO TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-success"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanKeyCardDone' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_tasksKeyCardDone_NotDone' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpanKeyCardDone' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanKeyCardDone' + id).html('<font class="text-danger">CLICK AND SOLVE TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-danger"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanKeyCardDone' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_tasksPortraitDone' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpanPortraitDone' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanPortraitDone' + id).html('<font class="text-success">CLICK AND GO TO TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-success"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanPortraitDone' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_tasksPortraitDone_NotDone' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpanPortraitDone' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanPortraitDone' + id).html('<font class="text-danger">CLICK AND SOLVE TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-danger"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanPortraitDone' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_tasksWhoIsWhoDone' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpanWhoIsWhoDone' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanWhoIsWhoDone' + id).html('<font class="text-success">CLICK AND GO TO TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-success"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanWhoIsWhoDone' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_tasksWhoIsWhoDone_NotDone' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpanWhoIsWhoDone' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanWhoIsWhoDone' + id).html('<font class="text-danger">CLICK AND SOLVE TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-danger"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanWhoIsWhoDone' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_tasksAGR' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpanAGR' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanAGR' + id).html('<font class="text-success">CLICK AND GO TO TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-success"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanAGR' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_tasksAGR_NotDone' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpanAGR' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanWhoIsAGR' + id).html('<font class="text-danger">CLICK AND SOLVE TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-danger"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanAGR' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_taskseTrack' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpaneTrack' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpaneTrack' + id).html('<font class="text-success">CLICK AND GO TO TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-success"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpaneTrack' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_taskseTrack_NotDone' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpaneTrack' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanWhoIseTrack' + id).html('<font class="text-danger">CLICK AND SOLVE TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-danger"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpaneTrack' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_tasksPhone' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpanPhone' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanPhone' + id).html('<font class="text-success">CLICK AND GO TO TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-success"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanPhone' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_tasksPhone_NotDone' + id).hover(
  function() {
    $originalText = $('.TaskTextSpanPhone' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanPhone' + id).html('<font class="text-danger">CLICK AND SOLVE TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-danger"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanPhone' + id).html($originalText);
  }
);
```

```css
.tr_user_tasks:hover {
  background: #e9ecef;
}

.hand_user_tasks {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrowbounce {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  right: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-15px);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-15px);
  }
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hourglass-small {
  font-size: .2em;
}

.hourglass {
  width: 3.5em;
  height: 5em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2.5em 1.2em;
  border-color: #ffc107 transparent;
  border-radius: 10%;
  position: relative;
  animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
}

.hourglass:before {
  content: "";
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 4.5em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2.25em 1.1em;
  border-color: white transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.25em;
  left: -.7em;
  animation: slideOut 5s linear infinite;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hourglass:after {
  content: "";
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 4.5em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0em 1.1em;
  border-color: transparent transparent white;
  border-radius: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.25em;
  left: -.7em;
  animation: slideIn 5s linear infinite;
  color: #ffc107;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotation(0deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes slideOut {
  0% {
    top: -2.25em;
    width: 2.5;
    border-width: 2.25em 1.1em;
  }
  90% {
    top: 0em;
    width: 0;
    border-width: 0em 0em;
    left: .55em;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0em;
    width: 0;
    border-width: 0em 0em;
    left: .55em;
  }
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    border-width: 0em 1.1em;
  }
  90% {
    border-width: 2.25em 1.1em;
  }
  100% {
    border-width: 2.25em 1.1em;
  }
}

.fa-beat {
  animation: fa-beat 5s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes fa-beat {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  5% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  35% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  55% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e3a6e5f796.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table>
  <tr style="border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;" class="tr-hover" data-href="flow.asp?ShowPagePart=FlowNotDone&GetSpecificUserOnFlow=yes&UserIDOnFlow=315">
    <td>
      <div class="blob red" id="StatusToolTipJoinLess50Percent">
        <center>
          <font style="color: #FFFFFF;"><b>T</b></font>
        </center>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>Some Name</td>
    <td>28-05-2021</td>
    <td>40,00 %</td>
    <tr>
      <tr style="border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;">
        <td colspan="4">

          <div role="row" class="progress shadow mb-2 bg-gray" aria-colspan="4">
            <div role="cell" aria-colspan="4" class="progress-bar
                      bg-danger
                      " role="progressbar" style="width: 40%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">40,00%</div>
          </div>

          <table style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="1" colspan="1">

            <tr id="tr_user_tasksIT_NotDone315" class="tr_user_tasks hand_user_tasks" onclick="window.location='confirm_tasks_solved.asp?RoleType=IT2&id=315';">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-danger  fa-beat"></i></td>
              <td>
                <div class="TaskTextSpanIT315" style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep1 - Info received - awaits you</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="tr_user_tasksCFO315" class="tr_user_tasks hand_user_tasks" onclick="window.location='confirm_tasks_solved.asp?RoleType=cfo&id=315';">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;"><i class="fas fa-check text-success"></i></td>
              <td>
                <div class="TaskTextSpanCFO315" style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep2 - Finished d. 05-05-2021</b></font>
                  <DIV>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="tr_user_tasksEconomy_NotDone315" class="tr_user_tasks hand_user_tasks" onclick="window.location='sallary_info.asp?RoleType=economy&id=315';">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-danger  fa-beat"></i></td>
              <td>
                <div class="TaskTextSpanEconomy315" style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep 3 - Adviced 05-05-2021 - awaits you</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="tr_user_tasksAcademy315" class="tr_user_tasks">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;">
                <div class="hourglass hourglass-small"></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep3 - Not yet Adviced - awaits Some Person</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="tr_user_tasks">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;">
                <div class="hourglass hourglass-small"></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep4 - Not yet Adviced - awaits Some Person</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="tr_user_tasks">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;">
                <div class="hourglass hourglass-small"></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep5 - Not yet Adviced - awaits Some Person</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="tr_user_tasksWelcomePackage_NotDone315" class="tr_user_tasks hand_user_tasks" onclick="window.location='confirm_tasks_solved.asp?RoleType=WelcomePackage&id=315';">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-danger  fa-beat"></i></td>
              <td>
                <div class="TaskTextSpanWelcomePackage315" style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep6 - Adviced 05-05-2021 - awaits you</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="tr_user_tasksKeyCardDone315" class="tr_user_tasks hand_user_tasks" onclick="window.location='confirm_tasks_solved.asp?RoleType=AccessKey&id=315';">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;"><i class="fas fa-check text-success"></i></td>
              <td>
                <div class="TaskTextSpanKeyCardDone315" style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep7 - Finished d. 05-05-2021</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="tr_user_tasksPortraitDone_NotDone315" class="tr_user_tasks hand_user_tasks" onclick="window.location='confirm_tasks_solved.asp?RoleType=Portrait&id=315';">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-danger  fa-beat"></i></td>
              <td>
                <div class="TaskTextSpanPortraitDone315" style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep8 - Adviced 05-05-2021 - awaits you</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="tr_user_tasks">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;">
                <div class="hourglass hourglass-small"></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep9 - Not yet Adviced - awaits Some Person</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="tr_user_tasks">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;">
                <div class="hourglass hourglass-small"></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep10 - Not yet Adviced - awaits Some Person</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="tr_user_tasks">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;">
                <div class="hourglass hourglass-small"></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep11 - Not yet Adviced - awaits Some Person</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="tr_user_tasksPhone_NotDone315" class="tr_user_tasks hand_user_tasks" onclick="window.location='confirm_tasks_solved.asp?RoleType=Phone&id=315';">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-danger  fa-beat"></i></td>
              <td>
                <div class="TaskTextSpanPhone315" style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep12 - Adviced 05-05-2021 - awaits you</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

          </table>

        </td>
        <tr>
</table>
```

UPDATE : Current jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var id = <%=objFlowNotDoneMainPage("ID")%>
    
    $( '#tr_user_tasksIT' + id ).hover(
    function() {
        $originalText['.TaskTextSpanIT' + id] = $( '.TaskTextSpanIT' + id ).html();
        $( '.TaskTextSpanIT' + id ).html('<font class="text-success">KLIK FOR AT GÅ TIL DEN LØSTE OPGAVE</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-success"></i>');
    }, function() {
        $( '.TaskTextSpanIT' + id ).html( $originalText['.TaskTextSpanIT' + id] );
    }
    );

    $( '#tr_user_tasksIT_NotDone' + id ).hover(
    function() {
        $originalText['.TaskTextSpanIT' + id] = $( '.TaskTextSpanIT' + id ).html();
        $( '.TaskTextSpanIT' + id ).html('<font class="text-danger">GÅ TIL OPGAVEN OG MARKERE DEN SOM LØST</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-danger"></i>');
    }, function() {
        $( '.TaskTextSpanIT' + id ).html( $originalText['.TaskTextSpanIT' + id] );
    }
    );

});
```

I i.e tried toadd the check like this:

```
}, function() {
   if((originalText['.TaskTextSpanIT' + id] || "") === "") originalText['.TaskTextSpanIT' + id] = newText
   $( '.TaskTextSpanIT' + id ).html( newText );
}
```

Which does not work

Comment: You only have a single `$originalText`.  So if you quickly switch between them, the single (global) `$originalText` will still be the changed text of the previous item (or something like that).  Store/retrive  the originalText in a `$(this).data("originalText", ...html()` so that you're not using the same variable for multiple rows.

Comment: You could also use an array:  `originalText['.TaskTextSpanIT' + id]` and, to completely stop the issue, set it only once (ie check if it exists first)

Comment: Thanks I will test both your ways .. @freedomn-m , could you give me an example on "set it only once (ie check if it exists first)"? :-)

Comment: `originalText['.TaskTextSpanIT' + id] = originalText['.TaskTextSpanIT' + id] || newtext` - or - `if((originalText['.TaskTextSpanIT' + id] || "") === "") originalText['.TaskTextSpanIT' + id] = newText`

Comment: Now I feel really stupid .. I think I totally misunderstand what you are trying to tell me .. I I have replaced $originalText = .. with `$originalText['.TaskTextSpanIT' + id] = $( '.TaskTextSpanIT' + id ).html();` and $( '.TaskTextSpanIT' + id ).ht... with `$( '.TaskTextSpanIT' + id ).html( $originalText['.TaskTextSpanIT' + id] );`  .. this gives me `Uncaught ReferenceError: $originalText is not defined at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous>` :-S

Comment: Add a `var $originalText=[]` at the top of your code (global) - your previous `$originalText` (object) was *inferred* at the global level - ie created automatically.

Comment: Perfect, thank you @freedomn-m, that was the part I was missing, I tried to define it in the local script .. its working better now than before, but I can still provoke the issue with the label so I am going to try to emplement the check now

Comment: Hi @freedomn-m .. I have tried varous ways of implementing the check if it exist, but none the combination I have tried is working .. can you help?  .. I have updated the question with "UPDATE : Current jQuery:"

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){ var $originalText=[]; ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original issue was that `$originalText` was a single variable that changed for each row, but the order of events can't be guaranteed.

So one element's hover-on will set a new value for originalText before the next element's hover-off has a chance to reset the value.

One option is to store the originalText as an array, based on the element's ID.

There are two parts:

- setup a variable

```
var originalText = [];
```

this was previously *implied* (created automatically) but is required for an array.

- set the value for each element

```
originalText['.TaskTextSpanIT' + id] = $('.TaskTextSpanIT' + id).html();
```

This can be extended to reduce the need to re-call `.html()` (and *potentially* get the updated html instead of the original html)

```
originalText['.TaskTextSpanIT' + id] = originalText['.TaskTextSpanIT' + id] || $('.TaskTextSpanIT' + id).html();
```

(note, newer versions of javascript also have `||=` and `??=` which can be used instead of `x=x||y`)

Updating your snippet, I also now see that you have two elements hover, which both change the same element, so I've combined these to a single event handler.

A better option might be to include both bits of html in the code and simply `.toggle()` them.

```js
var id = 315

var originalText = [];

$('#tr_user_tasksIT' + id + ',#tr_user_tasksIT_NotDone' + id).hover(
  function() {
    originalText['.TaskTextSpanIT' + id] = originalText['.TaskTextSpanIT' + id] || $('.TaskTextSpanIT' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanIT' + id).html('<font class="text-success">CLICK AND GO TO TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-success"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanIT' + id).html(originalText['.TaskTextSpanIT' + id]);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_tasksCFO' + id + ',#tr_user_tasksCFO_NotDone' + id).hover(
  function() {
    originalText['.TaskTextSpanCFO' + id] = originalText['.TaskTextSpanCFO' + id] || $('.TaskTextSpanCFO' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanCFO' + id).html('<font class="text-success">CLICK AND GO TO TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-success"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanCFO' + id).html(originalText['.TaskTextSpanCFO' + id]);
  }
);

$('#tr_user_tasksEconomy' + id + ',#tr_user_tasksEconomy_NotDone' + id).hover(
  function() {
    originalText['.TaskTextSpanEconomy' + id] = originalText['.TaskTextSpanEconomy' + id] || $('.TaskTextSpanEconomy' + id).html();
    $('.TaskTextSpanEconomy' + id).html('<font class="text-success">CLICK AND GO TO TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-success"></i>');
  },
  function() {
    $('.TaskTextSpanEconomy' + id).html(originalText['.TaskTextSpanEconomy' + id]);
  }
);
```

```css
.tr_user_tasks:hover {
  background: #e9ecef;
}

.hand_user_tasks {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrowbounce {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  right: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-15px);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-15px);
  }
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hourglass-small {
  font-size: .2em;
}

.hourglass {
  width: 3.5em;
  height: 5em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2.5em 1.2em;
  border-color: #ffc107 transparent;
  border-radius: 10%;
  position: relative;
  animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
}

.hourglass:before {
  content: "";
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 4.5em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2.25em 1.1em;
  border-color: white transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.25em;
  left: -.7em;
  animation: slideOut 5s linear infinite;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hourglass:after {
  content: "";
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 4.5em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0em 1.1em;
  border-color: transparent transparent white;
  border-radius: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.25em;
  left: -.7em;
  animation: slideIn 5s linear infinite;
  color: #ffc107;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotation(0deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes slideOut {
  0% {
    top: -2.25em;
    width: 2.5;
    border-width: 2.25em 1.1em;
  }
  90% {
    top: 0em;
    width: 0;
    border-width: 0em 0em;
    left: .55em;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0em;
    width: 0;
    border-width: 0em 0em;
    left: .55em;
  }
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    border-width: 0em 1.1em;
  }
  90% {
    border-width: 2.25em 1.1em;
  }
  100% {
    border-width: 2.25em 1.1em;
  }
}

.fa-beat {
  animation: fa-beat 5s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes fa-beat {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  5% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  35% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  55% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e3a6e5f796.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table>
  <tr style="border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;" class="tr-hover" data-href="flow.asp?ShowPagePart=FlowNotDone&GetSpecificUserOnFlow=yes&UserIDOnFlow=315">
    <td>
      <div class="blob red" id="StatusToolTipJoinLess50Percent">
        <center>
          <font style="color: #FFFFFF;"><b>T</b></font>
        </center>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>Some Name</td>
    <td>28-05-2021</td>
    <td>40,00 %</td>
    <tr>
      <tr style="border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;">
        <td colspan="4">

          <div role="row" class="progress shadow mb-2 bg-gray" aria-colspan="4">
            <div role="cell" aria-colspan="4" class="progress-bar
                      bg-danger
                      " role="progressbar" style="width: 40%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">40,00%</div>
          </div>

          <table style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="1" colspan="1">

            <tr id="tr_user_tasksIT_NotDone315" class="tr_user_tasks hand_user_tasks" onclick="window.location='confirm_tasks_solved.asp?RoleType=IT2&id=315';">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-danger  fa-beat"></i></td>
              <td>
                <div class="TaskTextSpanIT315" style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep1 - Info received - awaits you</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="tr_user_tasksCFO315" class="tr_user_tasks hand_user_tasks" onclick="window.location='confirm_tasks_solved.asp?RoleType=cfo&id=315';">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;"><i class="fas fa-check text-success"></i></td>
              <td>
                <div class="TaskTextSpanCFO315" style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep2 - Finished d. 05-05-2021</b></font>
                  <DIV>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="tr_user_tasksEconomy_NotDone315" class="tr_user_tasks hand_user_tasks" onclick="window.location='sallary_info.asp?RoleType=economy&id=315';">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-danger  fa-beat"></i></td>
              <td>
                <div class="TaskTextSpanEconomy315" style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep 3 - Adviced 05-05-2021 - awaits you</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="tr_user_tasksAcademy315" class="tr_user_tasks">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;">
                <div class="hourglass hourglass-small"></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep3 - Not yet Adviced - awaits Some Person</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="tr_user_tasks">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;">
                <div class="hourglass hourglass-small"></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep4 - Not yet Adviced - awaits Some Person</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="tr_user_tasks">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;">
                <div class="hourglass hourglass-small"></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep5 - Not yet Adviced - awaits Some Person</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="tr_user_tasksWelcomePackage_NotDone315" class="tr_user_tasks hand_user_tasks" onclick="window.location='confirm_tasks_solved.asp?RoleType=WelcomePackage&id=315';">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-danger  fa-beat"></i></td>
              <td>
                <div class="TaskTextSpanWelcomePackage315" style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep6 - Adviced 05-05-2021 - awaits you</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="tr_user_tasksKeyCardDone315" class="tr_user_tasks hand_user_tasks" onclick="window.location='confirm_tasks_solved.asp?RoleType=AccessKey&id=315';">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;"><i class="fas fa-check text-success"></i></td>
              <td>
                <div class="TaskTextSpanKeyCardDone315" style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep7 - Finished d. 05-05-2021</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="tr_user_tasksPortraitDone_NotDone315" class="tr_user_tasks hand_user_tasks" onclick="window.location='confirm_tasks_solved.asp?RoleType=Portrait&id=315';">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-danger  fa-beat"></i></td>
              <td>
                <div class="TaskTextSpanPortraitDone315" style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep8 - Adviced 05-05-2021 - awaits you</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="tr_user_tasks">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;">
                <div class="hourglass hourglass-small"></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep9 - Not yet Adviced - awaits Some Person</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="tr_user_tasks">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;">
                <div class="hourglass hourglass-small"></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep10 - Not yet Adviced - awaits Some Person</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="tr_user_tasks">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;">
                <div class="hourglass hourglass-small"></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep11 - Not yet Adviced - awaits Some Person</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="tr_user_tasksPhone_NotDone315" class="tr_user_tasks hand_user_tasks" onclick="window.location='confirm_tasks_solved.asp?RoleType=Phone&id=315';">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-danger  fa-beat"></i></td>
              <td>
                <div class="TaskTextSpanPhone315" style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep12 - Adviced 05-05-2021 - awaits you</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

          </table>

        </td>
        <tr>
</table>
```

You can also **substantially** reduce the amount of code you need (but I didn't check *every* bit of text was the same, so shows an idea only)

```js
var id = 315

var originalText = [];

$(".tr_user_tasks").hover(
  function() {
    originalText[this.id] = originalText[this.id] || $(this).find("td:eq(1)>div").html();
    // if this had a different class, it would be easier to find, but class has an id munged
    // :eq() is deprecated, so add a class to the 2nd td
    $(this).find("td:eq(1)>div").html('<font class="text-success">CLICK AND GO TO TASK</font> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-success"></i>')
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find("td:eq(1)>div").html(originalText[this.id]);
  });
```

```css
.tr_user_tasks:hover {
  background: #e9ecef;
}

.hand_user_tasks {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrowbounce {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  right: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-15px);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-15px);
  }
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hourglass-small {
  font-size: .2em;
}

.hourglass {
  width: 3.5em;
  height: 5em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2.5em 1.2em;
  border-color: #ffc107 transparent;
  border-radius: 10%;
  position: relative;
  animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
}

.hourglass:before {
  content: "";
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 4.5em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2.25em 1.1em;
  border-color: white transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.25em;
  left: -.7em;
  animation: slideOut 5s linear infinite;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hourglass:after {
  content: "";
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 4.5em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0em 1.1em;
  border-color: transparent transparent white;
  border-radius: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.25em;
  left: -.7em;
  animation: slideIn 5s linear infinite;
  color: #ffc107;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotation(0deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes slideOut {
  0% {
    top: -2.25em;
    width: 2.5;
    border-width: 2.25em 1.1em;
  }
  90% {
    top: 0em;
    width: 0;
    border-width: 0em 0em;
    left: .55em;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0em;
    width: 0;
    border-width: 0em 0em;
    left: .55em;
  }
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    border-width: 0em 1.1em;
  }
  90% {
    border-width: 2.25em 1.1em;
  }
  100% {
    border-width: 2.25em 1.1em;
  }
}

.fa-beat {
  animation: fa-beat 5s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes fa-beat {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  5% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  35% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  55% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e3a6e5f796.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table>
  <tr style="border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;" class="tr-hover" data-href="flow.asp?ShowPagePart=FlowNotDone&GetSpecificUserOnFlow=yes&UserIDOnFlow=315">
    <td>
      <div class="blob red" id="StatusToolTipJoinLess50Percent">
        <center>
          <font style="color: #FFFFFF;"><b>T</b></font>
        </center>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>Some Name</td>
    <td>28-05-2021</td>
    <td>40,00 %</td>
    <tr>
      <tr style="border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;">
        <td colspan="4">

          <div role="row" class="progress shadow mb-2 bg-gray" aria-colspan="4">
            <div role="cell" aria-colspan="4" class="progress-bar
                      bg-danger
                      " role="progressbar" style="width: 40%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">40,00%</div>
          </div>

          <table style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="1" colspan="1">

            <tr id="tr_user_tasksIT_NotDone315" class="tr_user_tasks hand_user_tasks" onclick="window.location='confirm_tasks_solved.asp?RoleType=IT2&id=315';">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-danger  fa-beat"></i></td>
              <td>
                <div class="TaskTextSpanIT315" style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep1 - Info received - awaits you</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="tr_user_tasksCFO315" class="tr_user_tasks hand_user_tasks" onclick="window.location='confirm_tasks_solved.asp?RoleType=cfo&id=315';">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;"><i class="fas fa-check text-success"></i></td>
              <td>
                <div class="TaskTextSpanCFO315" style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep2 - Finished d. 05-05-2021</b></font>
                  <DIV>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="tr_user_tasksEconomy_NotDone315" class="tr_user_tasks hand_user_tasks" onclick="window.location='sallary_info.asp?RoleType=economy&id=315';">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-danger  fa-beat"></i></td>
              <td>
                <div class="TaskTextSpanEconomy315" style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep 3 - Adviced 05-05-2021 - awaits you</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="tr_user_tasksAcademy315" class="tr_user_tasks">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;">
                <div class="hourglass hourglass-small"></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep3 - Not yet Adviced - awaits Some Person</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="tr_user_tasks">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;">
                <div class="hourglass hourglass-small"></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep4 - Not yet Adviced - awaits Some Person</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="tr_user_tasks">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;">
                <div class="hourglass hourglass-small"></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep5 - Not yet Adviced - awaits Some Person</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="tr_user_tasksWelcomePackage_NotDone315" class="tr_user_tasks hand_user_tasks" onclick="window.location='confirm_tasks_solved.asp?RoleType=WelcomePackage&id=315';">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-danger  fa-beat"></i></td>
              <td>
                <div class="TaskTextSpanWelcomePackage315" style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep6 - Adviced 05-05-2021 - awaits you</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="tr_user_tasksKeyCardDone315" class="tr_user_tasks hand_user_tasks" onclick="window.location='confirm_tasks_solved.asp?RoleType=AccessKey&id=315';">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;"><i class="fas fa-check text-success"></i></td>
              <td>
                <div class="TaskTextSpanKeyCardDone315" style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep7 - Finished d. 05-05-2021</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="tr_user_tasksPortraitDone_NotDone315" class="tr_user_tasks hand_user_tasks" onclick="window.location='confirm_tasks_solved.asp?RoleType=Portrait&id=315';">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-danger  fa-beat"></i></td>
              <td>
                <div class="TaskTextSpanPortraitDone315" style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep8 - Adviced 05-05-2021 - awaits you</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="tr_user_tasks">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;">
                <div class="hourglass hourglass-small"></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep9 - Not yet Adviced - awaits Some Person</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="tr_user_tasks">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;">
                <div class="hourglass hourglass-small"></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep10 - Not yet Adviced - awaits Some Person</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="tr_user_tasks">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;">
                <div class="hourglass hourglass-small"></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep11 - Not yet Adviced - awaits Some Person</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="tr_user_tasksPhone_NotDone315" class="tr_user_tasks hand_user_tasks" onclick="window.location='confirm_tasks_solved.asp?RoleType=Phone&id=315';">
              <td align="center" style="width: 30px;"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-danger  fa-beat"></i></td>
              <td>
                <div class="TaskTextSpanPhone315" style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                  <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Dep12 - Adviced 05-05-2021 - awaits you</b></font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

          </table>

        </td>
        <tr>
</table>
```